# Proxy error - Error during SSL Handshake (ubuntu server)

Tags: node.js, ssl, server, proxy, apache2

I have a web application in node js, which is running on port 3000. I can't get it to work with the ssl certificates, I get the following:

[image]

/etc/apache2/domain.conf configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass  / https://***.es:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse   / https://***.es:3000/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /certs/certificateSSL.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /certs/keySSL.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile  /certs/DigiCertCA.crt

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ***.es
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerAlias www.***.es

     
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It looks like the ssl is correct, but I can't fix the proxy error:

[image]

And I get the following error when I tail /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Mon Jan 16 17:47:29.698548 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 22330:tid 140606592464640] [client ****:54470] AH01097: pass request body failed to *****:3000 (****.es) from **** ()
```

What can i do?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry, I have already modified it

Answer (score 0):

Given that you ProxyPass to something at port 3000 and it is a common setup to have some backend at this port **which is not by itself https enabled** you likely have your ProxyPass (and ProxyPassReverse) directive wrong. Try to use it with `http://...`, not `https://...` - the method **should reflect what protocol the internal server actually speaks and not what protocol you want to use for the reverse proxy**.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! Correct, I have the backend on port 3000. I tried to make the change you told me, and now the error I get is **Invalid Host header**. What can it be?

Comment: @IvannVerano: *"... now the error I get is Invalid Host header. What can it be?"* - so it looks like your question was answered but now you have a new one. Please don't ask new question in comments to existing ones. Anyway, your application is expecting a different hostname than you use to access it. You've used `ProxyPreserveHost` to use the host header from the original URL given by the user but your internal application wants a different one, maybe the one you gave in the ProxyPass URL.